# Create new variable by matching strings

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame, ‘`df`’. The data frame is quite large. The data is quite fuzzy; it contains misspells, no constant pattern  etc. see example

```
structure(list(ABC = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 
11L, 2L, 7L, 10L), .Label = c("2-8-2010  14:42:00 (number not ok)", 
"2-8-2010  18:42:00 (nuber is not oke)", "2-8-2010  18:42:00 (number is not ok)", 
"2-9-2010  14:47:00 (? Not ok )", "23:59 missing &^%", "26-9-2010 23.24", 
"26-9-2010 23.24 not (working)", "26-9-2010 23.28 note: shutdown number!)", 
"26-9-2010 23.29 (missing brackets", "Im oke and working\n", 
"number"), class = "factor")), .Names = "ABC", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Q) How to recode a string variable based on a match with a target string?**

In my case how to recode a the variable ‘ABC’ when the strings matches the words *“not working”* and *“number is not ok”* and when there is a match, create variable XYZ labeled ‘present’ etc. I’m aiming for this:

```
structure(list(ABC = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 
1L, 12L, 3L, 8L, 11L), .Label = c("", "2-8-2010  14:42:00 (number not ok)", 
"2-8-2010  18:42:00 (nuber is not oke)", "2-8-2010  18:42:00 (number is not ok)", 
"2-9-2010  14:47:00 (? Not ok )", "23:59 missing &^%", "26-9-2010 23.24", 
"26-9-2010 23.24 not (working)", "26-9-2010 23.28 note: shutdown number!)", 
"26-9-2010 23.29 (missing brackets", "Im oke and working\tabsent\n", 
"number"), class = "factor"), XYZ = structure(list(XYZ = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("absent", 
"missing", "present"), class = "factor")), .Names = "XYZ", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))), .Names = c("ABC", "XYZ"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I know, there are some examples on Stack that look the same but, I could not getting them working. I hope someone can push me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different solution without grep. You can add as many clauses as you want to.

regexpr('string_to_look_for',variable) returns the position in the string.  So if that evaluates to anything other than zero, it found the string.

```
df$XYZ <- ifelse(regexpr('number is not ok',df$ABC)>0 |
                     regexpr('not working',df$ABC)>0 |
                     regexpr('not',df$ABC)>0,"present","absent")

                                   ABC     XYZ
1       2-8-2010  14:42:00 (number not ok) present
2    2-8-2010  18:42:00 (number is not ok) present
3           2-9-2010  14:47:00 (? Not ok )  absent
4                          26-9-2010 23.24  absent
5  26-9-2010 23.28 note: shutdown number!) present
6        26-9-2010 23.29 (missing brackets  absent
7                        23:59 missing &^%  absent
8                                   number  absent
9    2-8-2010  18:42:00 (nuber is not oke) present
10           26-9-2010 23.24 not (working) present
11                    Im oke and working\n  absent
```

Notice that the last clause looking for 'not' actually found that in "note". If you know exactly the strings to look for you can hard code them. @mlegge code is much more elegant, but harder to understand if you are a noob like me.

Comment: Thank you @aKaDrHouse, for pointing out the 'regexpr' solution. 
for the solution is as you say easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
> df$XYZ <- ifelse(grepl("not.*working|number.*[is]?.*not.*ok", df$ABC, ignore.case = TRUE), "present", "absent")
> df
                                       ABC     XYZ
1       2-8-2010  14:42:00 (number not ok) present
2    2-8-2010  18:42:00 (number is not ok) present
3           2-9-2010  14:47:00 (? Not ok )  absent
4                          26-9-2010 23.24  absent
5  26-9-2010 23.28 note: shutdown number!)  absent
6        26-9-2010 23.29 (missing brackets  absent
7                        23:59 missing &^%  absent
8                                   number  absent
9    2-8-2010  18:42:00 (nuber is not oke)  absent
10           26-9-2010 23.24 not (working) present
11                    Im oke and working\n  absent
```

Comment: thank you @mlegge, an up for the 'grepl'. I've also tried it with 'grepl' but I could not get it working, now I see my errors.